# .groupby function in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pie chart in Python. I have a dataset with 2137 responses to a question, with answer choices ranging from 1 to 5. I am trying to produce a pie chart with the percentage of responses for each answer choice, but when I run my code, it produce a pie chart of each respondent (so 2137 pieces of the pie. I am thinking I need to use the .groupby function,  but I am not entirely sure on how to correctly do it.

```html
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Q78']).groupby(['Q78'])
df3.plot.pie(subplots=True)
```

Here is what I have tried. (PS I am just starting to learn Python, so sorry if this is a dumb question!!)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is not that your question is dump. Pandas is a powerful package that takes time to learn. The problem with your question though is that it is far from complete. Without knowing anything about the contents and format of `df` we can only guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
s = df.Q87
s.groupby(s).size().plot.pie(autopct='%1.1f%%');
```

To test my code I created a Datarame limited to just 8 answers:

```
  Q87
0   A
1   B
2   C
3   D
4   E
5   A
6   B
7   A
```

and I got the following picture:

[image]